# Squid on Ubuntu 20.04 installation problem, acl command not found

Tags: 20.04, proxy, squid, acl, squid-deb-proxy

I'm new to Linux so please be patient with me.

I am following [this guide on phoenixnap.com to set up squid](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/setup-install-squid-proxy-server-ubuntu).

Squid successfully installed & is running.

However, `acl localnet src 192.168.0.15`, or similar command returns the following response:

```
Command 'acl' not found, but there are 17 similar ones
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The line you mentioned starting `acl` is configuration data, not a command.

According to the guide you were following, you need to open the file `/etc/squid/squid.conf` with a text editor, for example by running the command

```
sudo nano /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

And then **add** the line starting `acl` to that file, perhaps at the end, and perhaps with a comment to tell you what it is there for in future...

```
# give access permission 
acl localnet src 192.168.0.15
```

After adding the new text, save the file and exit (the nano text editor has instructions for these actions at the bottom of the window). The guide says that you should then restart the squid service.

Previous steps in the guide also required editing that file, so if you didn't follow them you may need to backtrack and check the earlier steps to get everything working.

Comment: see the link above. it said that:Create an access control list by editing the squid.conf file again, as in Step 4.
Add a new line as follows:
acl localnet src 192.168.0.15

Comment: than for your advice, and thanks for the editor. I’ll try to make the answer more clearly.